# Image is not updating in UI in ionic 2.How can I show the change image in dynamically?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am taking pic from camera and uploading to server , then returning the url of picture from server.But previous picture is still there.Image is not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a variable in TYPESCRIPT something like :

```
path:String = "";
```

then the function to take a photo

```
    takePicture(){
        Camera.getPicture({
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            targetWidth: xxx,
            targetHeight: yyy
        }).then((imageData) => {
          // imageData is a base64 encoded string, 
            this.path = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
//create a function here to send the photo and the return will be the link
            this.path = getServerLink();
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
      }
```

then in HTML

```
      <img src="{{path}}"/>  
<!--or -->
    <img [src]="path" *ngIf="path" />
```